# OpenGL ES performance issue when UIView is partially offscreen

Tags: ios, opengl-es

I'm currently working on an OpenGL game, and recently began refactoring it to support iPhone in addition to iPad. In an attempt to give myself as little work as possible, I simply resized the containing EAGLView to 480 x 360 (to preserve the iPad aspect ratio) and shifted the view up so it's y origin lay at -20 (in order to centre the content, and as the edges could be cropped).

I found this resulted in jerky performance on the device (despite the CADisplay link reporting a frame duration that equated to 59-61 fps) and was at least 20% slower when compared side by side with the iPad version.

I then tried resizing the view to the screen size 480 x 320 and the performance returned to normal (though the rendered content no longer has the correct aspect ratio).

Why is it that the 'off screen' rendering causes a performance hit and why does the displaylink still think it is running at 60fps?

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is mostly a wild guess, but what about clipping regions? There was this hardware functionality that made it possible to mix windows and hardware accelerated graphics. Maybe it is not implemented very well on mobile devices.

You could, however, avoid making the UIView offscreen and try to use glViewport() to shift the parts of the view offscreen. While it seems to be the same, it is handled by a different part of the pipeline (the rasterizer), and should be much faster.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I ended up tweaking the viewport as you said and it now runs like a dream